# Ubuntu 16.04 - DNS problem when waking laptop up from suspend-mode

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, broadcom, resolv.conf

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Dell XPS 15 9550.

Since one week ago (which probably matches last kernel update), every time I wake up my Laptop from suspend-mode, it correctly connects to the WiFi, but then it can't resolve any hostname (Google Chrome raises "DNS FINISHED BAD_CONFIG" and even ssh can't resolve server names).

This happen only when waking laptop up from suspend-mode. If I run

`sudo service network-manager restart`

then everything comes back to normal. I really have no idea of what's happening. Config or sys changes may be occurred only through automatic updates (kernel updates included).

P.S. I've already tried to reset resolvconf when the problem occurs, but no luck.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

just found this in syslog

```
brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
```

The strange thing is that I have an `brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin` in `/lib/firmware` , but it has extension `.bin` as all others drivers, so I don't know why the kernel is searching for an `.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

I fixed it by disabling dnsmasq in network manager configuration

1. commenting out `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
2. `sudo service network-manager restart`

(I found this workaround on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837575/dns-resolution-fails-after-wakeup-from-standby-ubuntu-16-10))

Comment: Is this an answer?